# WCF hardware requirement

Tags: .net, wcf

I read the hardware requirements of WCF in a book and two of them are the following ones:

- A DVD-ROM drive
- A 1024 × 768 or higher resolution display with 256 colors or more

Why is there a requirement for the screen resolution, or to have a DVD drive?

Perhaps, this requirement is necessary for Visual Studio to work. Am I wrong?

Comment: That's for the much lamented NetDvdBinding, don't worry no one uses this transport binding anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are probably the requirements to use the software (such as samples) included on the DVD with the book or if WCF was ever to be distributed on DVD. It is also likely to be a copy and paste error.